# Delete button not showing on UITableViewCell with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rounded-corners

In my tableview, I have logic in my `tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to determine if a cell has rounded corners on top, bottom, or no rounded corners at all.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // round top 2 corners
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner .TopLeft, UIRectCorner .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(4, 4)).CGPath
            cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
        }

        if indexPath.section != 1 {

            if indexPath.row == self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1 {
                let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner .BottomLeft, UIRectCorner .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(4, 4)).CGPath
                cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
            }
        }

    }
```

This works, but after I have implemented editing into the tableview, strange things happen to the delete button.

With the rounded corners code:

[image: with rounded corners]

When I remove the rounded corners:

[image: without rounded corners]

This really confuses me because I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried adding `cell.layer.maskToBounds = true` ?

Comment: You should probably not do this to the cell's view directly. Try and apply the layer mask to the cell's `contentView` instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // round top 2 corners
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner .TopLeft, UIRectCorner .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(4, 4)).CGPath
            cell.contentView.layer.mask = maskLayer
        }

        if indexPath.section != 1 {

            if indexPath.row == self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1 {
                let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner .BottomLeft, UIRectCorner .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(4, 4)).CGPath
                cell.contentView.layer.mask = maskLayer
            }
        }

    }
```

use cell.contentView.layer.mask = maskLayer

Comment: Hmmm... It shows the delete button, but the cell doesn't appear to be rounded. I tried to set the cell background color to clear and the contentView background color to white, which works, but the area around the red circle shows the tableview background.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is add a full size view with round corner on the uitableviewcell.

Comment: Please consider adding more details about your answer to help anyone understand the answer. Also, read [Stack Overflow answer guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)