# Masked UITablewViewCell and Delete Button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using rounded corners in UITableViewCell

```
                CAShapeLayer *shape         = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
                shape.path                  = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:topCell.bounds
                                                        cornerRadius:cornerRadius].CGPath;
                topCell.layer.mask          = shape;
                topCell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

and everything is good but when I'm using standard swipe-to-delete feature then DELETE button is not visible - because of mask applied, surely.

Any hints how to solve it? Somehow to limit mask to cell only? But what is strange that the cell is move to the left and the mask should be moved, too?

Comment: Try adding the mask to the table cell's `contentView`.  That is likely what is being moved when swipe to delete happens.

Comment: Thanks. I found the guy having basically same issue as me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087659/delete-button-not-showing-on-uitableviewcell-with-rounded-corners

Solution works but with limitations: 

a) as he writes, one needs to additionally set cell background to clear color, otherwise rounding is not visible due to the fact that cell itself remains rectangular 

b) But for the cell with accessory the contentView does not cover the whole cell - so the place around accessory view remains "empty" - I still did not found solution for that

Comment: What about using background image instead of round the corners